# Not recognising arbitrary keyword positional arguments using **kwarg format

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, keyword

I'm trying to implement a function with 2 arguments and an additional 3rd arbitrary keyword argument using `**kwarg` formatting, as below:

```
def build_profile(first_name, last_name, **additional_info):
    """ Building a user profile """
    profile = {}
    profile['First name'] = first_name
    profile['Last name'] = last_name
    for key, value in additional_info.items():
        profile[key.title()] = value.title()
    return profile

build_profile("x", 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y')
```

However, this produces the error:

```
TypeError: build_profile() takes 2 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

I managed to reproduce this error in isolation using the following code:

```
def x(**y):
    print(y)
```

Output:

```
x(1,2,3,4,5)
```

This generates the same response:

```
TypeError: x() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

This has lead me to conclude that I either:

1. Have an issue with my python configuration (running 3.6.4 in Spyder) or
2. I'm missing something blindingly obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are examples if you want minimalistic, understandable approaches.

```
>>> def x(*args):
...    for arg in args:
...        print(arg)

>>> x(1, 2, 3)
1
2
3

>>> def x(**kwargs):
...    for k, v in kwargs.items():
...        print(k, v)

>>> x(name='john', surname='wick')
name john
surname wick
```

Answer (score 3):

The `**kwargs` syntax in a function signature is for accepting an arbitrary number of *keyword* arguments, i.e. arguments passed in like `f(name=value)`.

```
def f(**kwargs):
    # kwargs is a dict here
```

The syntax used for accepting an arbitrary number of *positional* arguments looks like `*args`:

```
def f(*args):
    # args is a tuple here
```

It's the `*` and `**` which make the syntax, this choice of names is just a convention - you can use other names if you want.  You may also specify both.

```
def f(*splat, **splattysplat):
    ...
```